# Reconsidering PhD?

Tags: mathematics, career-path

I don't know if this is the right question to ask, but I have been seriously reconsidering whether I want to continue with my PhD. I am currently a first year graduate student in mathematics (PhD track). I had wanted to get a PhD in mathematics since I was a freshman in college. I got into my top choice for graduate school, have already passed two prelims, and really enjoyed my first semester.

The prospect of being a professor has always interested me. I do not want a research position, in fact, I would prefer a job at a smaller liberal arts school. I have really enjoyed my time as an instructor much more than I expected and would enjoy a job that is more teaching focused.

However, I have heard multiple stories of people in my program applying for 70+ jobs. This seems very stressful to me and I am worried I cannot handle it. I also have geographic limitations. My entire family lives in new england, so I do not want to leave this area. I am also worried that I could be on short term contracts for several years of my life. It seems stressful to be entering a job and immediately start applying for new jobs.

All of this has really made me question whether or not to continue with my degree. I know that the jobs are scarce for research positions, and thought that I was being flexible with the prospect of working at more liberal arts schools. However, it seems to me that people are struggling to get jobs that are less research intensive. I do not want to leave my program (I am doing well in it and really enjoy it), but I have just been super stressed about the future.

I am nervous to talk to anybody about this because most people seem to not care about where they live and don't mind bouncing around from appointment to appointment. However, I do!! I feel like I am alone in caring about these things! Does anybody have any advice? Is this a sign that I might not be cut out for such a profession?

Comment: I don't have an exact count, but I would estimate there were about 10 permanent jobs that were advertised at liberal arts colleges in New England this year.  (Most of them advertise on Mathjobs, so you can go there and get an accurate count for yourself.) 
Each of those openings will get several hundred applications from people who meet the minimum qualifications, and probably at least 50-100 highly qualified candidates.  I assume you understand the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: Only you can decide whether the possible rewards of an academic career outweigh the cons of an extremely competitive job market.  It's a very subjective choice.  There are lots of available statistics that can help you to better understand what is going on, but even with that information you'll end up having to take a chance on an uncertain future.

Comment: To add to what @AlexanderWoo said, even professors at liberal arts schools are usually highly accomplished researchers and do research as a significant part of their job, so your perception that these jobs are not “research positions” or that they are “less research intensive” is not entirely accurate, although there is a kernel of truth in it.

Comment: @Dan, Thank you. I went to a small liberal arts college for undergrad and few of the faculty are actively publishing. I just wanted to be clear that I do not consider a non-research position a failure (as Drecate mentions).

Comment: Ok, that’s interesting. Perhaps it depends on the college. I know many excellent research mathematicians who are professors at liberal arts schools, so that’s the main source of my knowledge. It would be interesting to hear from more knowledgeable people on this question.

Comment: @Dan - there is a big difference between Amherst and Stonehill

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the contradiction in your situation is that you 1) want to become a professor at a smaller liberal arts college, but 2) don't want to go through the job search necessary (70+ applications, having to do postdocs where you move around constantly, etc) to get there. Unfortunately, you can't have both. You'll have to choose one or the other.

If you choose to become a professor then you'll have to put up with the job search process. That's just the way the job market is (see Alexander Woo's comment). If you can't put up with the job search process then you'll have to do something else for a job. Make sure you know what the jobs you can get are. Search your local job portal and see what jobs are available in New England to people with undergraduate Math degrees. See if you like any of those jobs. Then search your local job portal for jobs that require PhD Math degrees. See if you prefer those jobs. If yes, you have a fallback plan for if you don't get one of the few teaching professor jobs available. If not, then you might as well apply for those jobs now and quit the PhD if you get one. You might even be able to apply for a sabbatical in your PhD to let you "try out" the job, returning to the PhD if the job doesn't work out.

By the way: even in non-academic jobs, there will be competition, and the competition can be fierce. Expect to have to send at least 20+ applications. You will be more stable though, and not have to float between postdocs.

Comment: Thank you for your honesty and your post.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having specific needs when it comes to job search, and that does not disqualify you for a PhD. To really understand the current state of the job market a good place to start is to talk with people in your field who have recently been on the job market, even if they didn't share exactly the same concerns as you. In the end whether to get a PhD or not is a personal choice; if you can justify to yourself that there are jobs outside of liberal arts colleges that you want and that require PhD, then stick with it. Also keep in mind that there may be jobs in industry, government, consulting, etc. that may have some teaching component that could be a good fit for you.

Comment: Do you think that people in my department (specifically prospective advisors) will be concerned if I bring up such a matter?

Comment: well... there are certainly still people who believe that anything other than a tenure-track research position is a failure (and such positions are worth pursuing above all other concerns). Just be sure to avoid those people.

Comment: I am confused by the line "if you can justify to yourself that there are jobs outside of liberal arts colleges that you want and that require PhD, then stick with it." I work at a small liberal arts college. A PhD is required. So if the OP wants such a job, they should complete their PhD.